# Plesk - Error adding subdomain "The specified directory contains a service directory"

Tags: subdomain, plesk

I'm trying to create a subdomain and point it to `etc/subdomains/home`

Folder `home` only contains an index file.`

When I click ok I get this message:  "The specified directory contains a service directory"

I tried with`` `etc/subdomains/home `` and `etc/subdomains/home/index.php` but I still get the error message.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `etc` folder is reserved for configs and other staff, not sure what the one would want web scripts in there. Try choosing any other folder like `subdomain/home`, `htdocs/subdomain/home`, `subdomains/mysubdomain/home`, etc.